# Why test for matching \. if testing for matching anything but a specific character?

Tags: regex, perl

http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html says:

> The `extract_delimited` function formalizes the common idiom of extracting a single-character-delimited substring from the start of a string. For example, to extract a single-quote delimited string, the following code is typically used:
>
> ```
> ($remainder = $text) =~ s/\A('(\\.|[^'])*')//s;
> $extracted = $1;
> ```

`\\.` (which is `'\.'`) seems to be covered by `([^'])*`. Why is `\\.|` in there? Why not use `s/\A('[^']*')//s`?

Comment: Note to future readers: "`\\.` (which is `'\.'`)" in the question is **wrong**. The answer, below, fixes that assumption.

Comment: That's actually a bad regex; I'm surprised they used it.  It works okay on valid inputs, but it's prone to false positives on invalid ones, `"like \"this\""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'(\\.|[^'])*'` would match an escaped quote or escaped any special character like `'\'\"'` where `'[^']*'` won't match `'\''`, that's the main difference.

`'(\\.|[^'])*'`

- `'` matches a single quotes.
- `\\.` Match any escaped character. If there is no backslash then the control shift to the negated character class `[^']`. So this would greedily match all the escaped characters.
- `'` Match a single quote.

Comment: note that a regex is not good to parse strings which include escaped quotes (no regex can do that by definition), but it can be useful for simpler matches